# Scheduling a Task in VB ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I was reading into using Quartz http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_3.html but I don't understand how to implement.  I was also reading this https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/, also don't understand how to implement, specifically, where do I put it and how do I access my controllers/actions?

There is a comment on the article linked above that suggests to use, "... a simple timer in global.asax."  How can this be achieved?

Basically, I would like to know how (and what's the best way) to schedule the following action on the following controller?

```
Public Class RssController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Function InsertRssFeedItem(ByVal url as String) As ActionResult

      ' code to get RSS and insert into database '

    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally consider it bad practice to have a web server doing automation, I prefer that to be kept away in a service that is more suited to automated jobs.

That said, using the above artice, I would put the section titled using Quartz.net into the application_start in global.asax

In the application_end, shut down the job scheduler.

Finally, in a folder, write a class like:

**c#**

```
public class InsertRssFeedJob : IJob
{
     public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
     {
          var rssController = new RssController();
          rssController.InsertRssFeedItem("");
     }
}
```

**vb.net**

```
Public Class InsertRssFeedJob
    Implements IJob

    Public Sub Execute(context as JobExecutionContext)
        Dim rssContoller = new RssController()
        rssController.InsertRssFeedItem("")
    End Sub

End Class
```

<strike>Sorry, I don't know VB that well to write it outside of an IDE, so you will need to convert this c#.</strike>

```
 private static IScheduler _scheduler; 
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        _scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler();

        JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("rssFeedJob", null, typeof(InsertRssFeedJob));
        // fire every hour
        Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeHourlyTrigger();
        // start on the next even hour
        trigger.StartTime = TriggerUtils.GetEvenHourDate(DateTime.UtcNow);
        trigger.Name = "myTrigger";

        _scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger); 

    }

    protected void Application_End()
    {
        _scheduler.Shutdown();
    }
```

Also, if the RssController needs access to any context information, you will need to get that from the HttpContext class.

Si

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have a better understanding; but I don't know **what** to put in "section titled using Quartz.net into the application_start in global.asax."  Also, how do I shut down the job scheduler in application_end?

Comment: Here is a quick sample, this runs the trigger every hour, you will need to change that to match what you want

Comment: I was trying to use your code but I received an error.  I opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303637/how-to-implement-quartz-net-scheduler-for-simple-helloworld perhaps you can help since it's your code.