# How to implement Quartz.net Scheduler for simple HelloWorld

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

The following code produces the following error:

```
Imports Quartz
Imports Quartz.Impl

Public Class InsertRssFeedJob
    Implements IJob

    Public Sub Execute(context As JobExecutionContext)
        Dim rssContoller = New RssController()
        rssController.InsertRssFeedItem("")
    End Sub

End Class
```

> Error 1   Class 'InsertRssFeedJob' must implement 'Sub Execute(context As IJobExecutionContext)' for interface 'Quartz.IJob'. C:\Users\darchual\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MyBlog\MyBlog\QuartzScheduler\Class1.vb 5   16  MyBlog

I have added the library package reference and can import Quartz successfully, but "Implements `IJob`" has a blue line underneath of it and displays the error above.  What can I do?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is How I use it (first create scheduleFactory, in a different class/Sub)...

```
Dim schedFact As ISchedulerFactory = New StdSchedulerFactory()

' get a scheduler
Dim sched As IScheduler = schedFact.GetScheduler()
sched.Start()

' construct job info
Dim jobDetail As New JobDetail(TriggerName, Nothing, GetType(cls_schedule))
Dim trigger As Trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeDailyTrigger(hour, min)

trigger.StartTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow
trigger.Name = TriggerName
sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger)
```

I passed the class name "cls_schedule" to JobDetail, Then you can use your class (which was passed as parameter) to Excute the actuall task.

```
Public Class cls_schedule
    Implements IJob

    Public Sub Execute(ByVal context As Quartz.JobExecutionContext) Implements Quartz.IJob.Execute
        Dim jobType As String = context.Trigger.Name
                 ' Your Code Goes here
    End sub
```

Comment: Thanks, highwingers.  Where do I put these two?  I thought I was supposed to put something in Application_Start() in global.asax.

Comment: create two classes in app_code folder, then one will have the code i provided above and second one will be same as the one you already have.

Comment: code above i tried on windows application, but yes if its a webapp then you should put in Application_onstart, above code is schedule settings (in app_onstart). and then your actuall class which was passed to scheduled factory as parameter will do the actuiall Action (whenever job is excuted). please do keep in mind, when you change anything in scheduling you need to restart IIS, otherwise your new changes will NOT kick in.

Comment: Haven't been able to test yet, but I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

it is the signature on the execute method, change it to  IJobContext, that should solve it.

Comment: I changed what I thought was the signature but it didn't seem to work.  Maybe I am doing it wrong.  Could you post an example what you mean so that we're on the same page?  Thanks for your help.